# Compare the results of a loop one by one

Tags: php

I have a mysql database with numbers in example: 0655456246 or 0641698646 ...
I will search these results in my database with the following script:

```
    $result6=mysqli_query($conn2, "SELECT number FROM sms_stop");
    while ($check2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6))
    {
        $checknumber = implode(str_replace("+33", "0", $check2));
    }
```

I would now like to compare the results 1 by 1 to see if it corresponds with what the user put in a form field but the problem is that on the 2 numbers of the example the comparison works with the 0641698646 but Not with the 0655456246. I do not understand why .... I just want that if the user puts one of the numbers already present in the database it must refuse the access to him.

$Recipient => is the number entered by the user in the form

```
        if ($Recipient != $checknumber)
        {
          ...
        }

        else
        {
            echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">alert("ERROR")</script>';
        }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `WHERE` with SQL?

Comment: I want to select all the numbers of my database to compare with the number entered. If the number corresponds I block if it does not correspond to any number of the base I let pass

Comment: You could simply use `SELECT number FROM sms_stop WHERE number = *number*` and see if you get any result. That method is much easier if you ask me (although it doesn't explain why your current method doesn't work). Although you would have to protect yourself from SQL-injection.

Comment: Ok i will think about your solution thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted it looks like you are doing your check after the mysqli_fetch_assoc loop, which means $checknumber will only have the last value retrieved from the database. Try something like this :

```
$found=false;       
$result6=mysqli_query($conn2, "SELECT number FROM sms_stop");
while ($check2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6))
{
  $checknumber = implode(str_replace("+33", "0", $check2));
  if ($checknumber==$Recipient)
     $found=true;
}
if ($found==false)
{
...
}
else
echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">alert("ERROR")</script>';
```